# Merge subgroup into adjacent subgroup after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

If we run the following code

```
np.random.seed(0) 
features = ['f1','f2','f3']

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5000,4), columns=features+['target'])
for f in features:
    df[f] = np.digitize(df[f], bins=[0.13,0.66])
    df['target'] = np.digitize(df['target'], bins=[0.5]).astype(float)

df.groupby(features)['target'].agg(['mean','count']).head(9)
```

We get average values for each grouping of the feature set:

```
            mean    count
f1  f2  f3      
0   0   0   0.571429    7
        1   0.414634    41
        2   0.428571    28
    1   0   0.490909    55
        1   0.467337    199
        2   0.486726    113
    2   0   0.518519    27
        1   0.446281    121
        2   0.541667    72
```

In the table above, some of the groups has too few observations and I want to merge it into 'adjacent' group by some rules. For example, I may want to merge the group [0,0,0] with group [0,0,1] since it has no more than 30 observations. I wonder if there is any good way of operating such group combinations according to columns values without creating a separate dictionary? More specifically, I may want to merge from the smallest count group to its adjacent group (the next group within the index order) until the total number of groups is no more than 10.

Comment: Please use a random seed so we can easily reproduce the data.  Try putting this at the top of your code and update your post `np.random.seed(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do it is with a loop `for` on indexes meeting your condition:

```
df_group = df.groupby(features)['target'].agg(['mean','count'])
# Fist reset_index to get an easier manipulation
df_group = df_group.reset_index()
list_indexes = df_group[df_group['count'] <=58].index.values # put any value you want
# loop for on list_indexes
for ind in list_indexes:
    # check again your condition in case at the previous iteration 
    # merging the row has increase the count above your cirteria
    if df_group['count'].loc[ind] <= 58:
        # add the count values to the next row
        df_group['count'].loc[ind+1] = df_group['count'].loc[ind+1] + df_group['count'].loc[ind]
        # do anything you want on mean
        # drop the row
        df_group = df_group.drop(axis = 0, index = ind)
# Reindex your df
df_group = df_group.set_index(features)
```